# Make it so either 2 fields are Null or neither of them are in django?

Tags: python, django

I am making a model for my django app where I want to store some measurements, these measurements will have a reading that must not be Null, and a GPS position stored as Latitude and Longitude.

I want to accept measurements where there hasn't been a GPS fix yet, so Latitude and Longitude should be null. And in theory, the sensor will never send a Latitude without a longitude or vice versa.
Still, there is nothing in the django app that actually forbids that from happening, is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add `unique=True` for the points? So if the latitude and longitude are existent, you should raise errors to prevent adding it. Then you don't have to worry about null points as the object won't be added if there's an duplicate

Comment: Given how the sensor and gps work, it is possible that two readings report the same coordinates because the gps didn't update between measurements. Since it's more important to get every reading than getting different locations, it's not undesirable.
As I said, this is more of a sanity check to make sure another application doesn't accidentally send just latitudes to the database.

Comment: So all you want to check is to make sure whether there are both latitude and longitude in the data?

Comment: Basically yes. I want to make sure my model either accepts both latitude and longitude with data or both being null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe storing a GPS position as a dictionnary registered as a string could be a solution:

`dict = {'latitude': 0.00, 'longitude': 0.00}`

To do so, I would define the **position** as a **CharField**:

```py
from django.db import models

class GPS(models.Model):
    ...
    position = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...
```

Then, you may overload GPS's predefined **save()** method to check if both dimensions of position variable are not null:

```py
class GPS(models.Model):
    ...
    position = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.check_position()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The two steps of the new **save()** method are:

1. Call model method **check_position** that will make sure both latitude and longitude are not null
2. Call the initial **save()** method

The **check_position** method should do the following tasks:

1. Load the **position** field and convert it to a dict
2. Make sure both dimention are not null, update and save back into string

```py
import ast

class GPS(models.Model):
    ...
    position = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.check_position()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def check_position(self):
        # Load position as a dict
        position_dict = ast.literal_eval(self.position)

        # define a default position if one of dimentions is null
        default_dict = "{'latitude': 0.00, 'longitude': 0.00}"

        # test each dimensions
        if position_dict['latitude'] == 0: self.position = default_dict
        if position_dict['longitude'] == 0: self.position = default_dict
```

good luck

**UPDATE :**

Following your comment, having two floats is much simpler:

```py
class GPS(models.Model):
    ...
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.latitude == 0 or self.longitude == 0:
            self.latitude = 0
            self.longitude = 0
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Good luck

Comment: I did not know of the save method and how to override it. It probably makes more sense still to save the latitude and longitude as floats but being able to override the method to introduce a check for either both of them being null or neither would definetly solve my question. Thank you!

Comment: You can also save both as float and check them in the save method which is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you use a [PointField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield). This is not a usual field but something in GeoDjango -- a Django branch designed for storing geographical data. I do believe that you must provide two arguments for this to work.

```py
class YourModel(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField()
```

If this still doesn't work, then you might need to find ways to sanitize your user input through javascript.